# Get UserControl on Click Event

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I created a custom control which contains `panels`, `labels` and `pictureboxes`. I am trying to get get the `user controls` name property when its clicked event is called.

In my user control, I have the following code to bubble up the `click` event so any of the children controls can trigger the `click` event

```
    private void reclusiveControlLoop(ControlCollection Controls, EventHandler EventValue, Boolean Mode)
    {
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                reclusiveControlLoop(control.Controls, EventValue, Mode);
            }

            if (Mode)
            {
                control.Click += EventValue;
            }
            else
            {
                control.Click -= EventValue;
            }
        }
    }

    public new event EventHandler Click
    {
        add
        {
            base.Click += value;
            reclusiveControlLoop(pnlContent.Controls, value, true);
        }
        remove
        {
            base.Click -= value;
            reclusiveControlLoop(pnlContent.Controls, value, false);
        }
    }
```

The on the form which has the user control I added the following code

```
Private Sub ListLinkLaunch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles llCommissions.Click
        Try
            Dim llItem As Control = CType(sender, Control)
            Dim sName As String = llItem.Name.ToString()

            MessageBox.Show(sName)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The problem is it isn't returning the name of the control I added which is `llCommissions` but instead returning the name of the label of the user control `lblListLinkTitle`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting the controls name (`lblListLinkTitle` for example), is related to how you are assigning the `Click` event to each of the controls. As your code stands, each control is raising the `Click` event all the way up to the containing form.

To get your desired behaviour, each control should be raising their Click events to your custom control, and from there, raise a new event to the containing form.

In order to get it to work as you want, make these changes:

**Inside the UserControl.cs - Constructor after the call to InitializeComponent**

```
pnlContent.Click += AllControls_Click;
reclusiveControlLoop(pnlContent.Controls, true);
```

And, this is the rest of your code modified to work slightly differently.

```
private void AllControls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
}

private void reclusiveControlLoop(ControlCollection Controls, Boolean Mode)
{
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        if(control.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            reclusiveControlLoop(control.Controls, Mode);
        }

        if(Mode)
        {
            control.Click += AllControls_Click;
        }
        else
        {
            control.Click -= AllControls_Click;
        }
    }
}
```

With this method you no longer need to define the new Click EventHandler (`public new event EventHandler Click`)

What this means in practice is that on your Form, you will never know which control (`Label` or `PictureBox`) has been clicked, and that is how it should be, those details should not be passed to the root form.